# Cities Distance Matrix with latitude and longitude

Tags: r

I'm trying to find a matrix distance using latitude and longitude in R. My data frame has three columns the first column has the name of the areas(cities) the second column has the longitude, and the third column has the latitude. If I only select the longitude and the latitude columns I can get a matrix distance using the code below but what I want is to have the name of the cities on the matrix as well. Please note that the data in the code below has only two columns as I can't make the code below work on the cities column as well. I have 1152 rows in my data set. Your help is much appreciated.

```
dist_mat <- distm(data, fun = distGeo) 
dist_mat
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! :) Please have a look at [the guide to asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first. If you are able to provide some [representative code and data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that will help people try to help you.

Answer (score 2):

I have made a dataset `d` which has 10 cities. This code can be scaled for 1152 cities as well.

```
d <- data.frame(cities = letters[1:10], longitude = rnorm(10), latitude = rnorm(10))
library(geosphere)
dist_mat <- distm(d[, 2:3], fun = distGeo)
rownames(dist_mat) <- d$cities
colnames(dist_mat) <- d$cities
```

You just have to set `rownames` and `colnames` of your `dist_mat` equal to your `citie` names.